# how should I concatenate variables and strings in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of `parents`: `['a','b','c']`, 
and 3 lists of children:

```
$ctrl.aChildren = ['aa','aaa']
$ctrl.bChildren = ['bb','bbb']
$ctrl.cChildren = ['cc','ccc']
```

I'd like to access these 3 variables in the inner `<li>` using variable `parent` from outer `<li>`

```
<li ng-repeat="parent in $ctrl.parents">
    ....
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="child in $ctrl[{{parent}} + 'Children']">
        </li>
    </ul>
    ...
</li>
```

I got an error saying

> '{' is an unexpected

Thanks

Comment: try this `ng-repeat="child in $ctrl[parent+ 'Children']"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need put `{{}}`.It should be like this

```
 <li ng-repeat="parent in $ctrl.parents">
   {{parent}}
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="child in $ctrl[parent + 'Children']">
       {{child}}
     </li>
 </ul>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.parents = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  $ctrl.aChildren = ['aa', 'aaa']
  $ctrl.bChildren = ['bb', 'bbb']
  $ctrl.cChildren = ['cc', 'ccc']
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
  <li ng-repeat="parent in $ctrl.parents">
    {{parent}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="child in $ctrl[parent + 'Children']">
        {{child}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, too. `<!-- ngRepeat: child in $ctrl[parent + 'Children'] -->` my html became this.

Comment: Thanks, I found my error. I forgot to bind `aChildren` etc in the component.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to add {{}} inside ng-repeat directive. Replace the following code

```
<li ng-repeat="child in $ctrl[{{parent}} + 'Children']">
```

with

```
<li ng-repeat="child in $ctrl[parent + 'Children']">
```